# Sign up/in using google account for localhost application

Tags: php, ssl

I want to use "sign up/in using google account" on my localhost web application. I used the apis provided by google for this but it's not working.

it gives me the error

> HTTP Error: (0) couldn't connect to host

Is it necessary to have a security certificate (SSL) for localhost to use the api?

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

That can't be done I guess. You'll need a domain name or some DNS entry for the website on which you are trying to integrate the Google sign-in.

Comment: I meant, you'll need to register a domain with some company  and then host the site. The google server will then recognize from where the request is coming from?